# greenplum 6.9 gpexpand error bash: /bin/scp: No such file or directory

Tags: greenplum

I expand segment on existing servers, but occurred error:
`"bash: /bin/scp: No such file or directory"`
scp already installed, at slave28 server, the file
`/opt/data/gpdatap1/gpseg0/postgresql.conf` already
exists

below is log

```
20201116:16:07:30:016541 gpexpand:master27:gpadmin-[ERROR]:-gpexpand failed: ExecutionError: 'non-zero rc: 127' occurred. Details: 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 slave28 ". /usr/local/greenplum-db-6.9.0/greenplum_path.sh; /bin/scp /opt/data/gpdatap1/gpseg0/postgresql.conf master27:/opt/data/gpmaster/gpexpand_11162020_16541"' cmd had rc=127 completed=True halted=False
stdout=''
stderr='bash: /bin/scp: No such file or directory
'

Exiting...
20201116:16:07:30:016541 gpexpand:master27:gpadmin-[ERROR]:-Please run 'gpexpand -r' to rollback to the original state.


**The gpexpand file contents**

slave28|slave28|6002|/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg12|14|12|p
slave28|slave28|6003|/opt/data/gpdatap4/gpseg13|15|13|p
slave29|slave29|6002|/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg14|16|14|p
slave29|slave29|6003|/opt/data/gpdatap4/gpseg15|17|15|p
slave31|slave31|6002|/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg16|18|16|p
slave31|slave31|6003|/opt/data/gpdatap4/gpseg17|19|17|p
slave32|slave32|6002|/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg18|20|18|p
slave32|slave32|6003|/opt/data/gpdatap4/gpseg19|21|19|p
slave33|slave33|6002|/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg20|22|20|p
slave33|slave33|6003|/opt/data/gpdatap4/gpseg21|23|21|p
slave34|slave34|6002|/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg22|24|22|p
slave34|slave34|6003|/opt/data/gpdatap4/gpseg23|25|23|p

scp already installed

[gpadmin@master27 ~]$ /bin/scp
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
[gpadmin@master27 ~]$ scp
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you have `scp` installed on the `slave28`? From the snippets, you were testing the `scp` command on `master27`.

Comment: Yes,Thank you very much.on the slave28,scp already installed,but no path /usr/bin/scp.only  /usr/local/bin/scp 。use ln command,the question is resolved. thank you.